# Updating a specific row in an SQL table selected by a drop-down list in PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql

I've been making a Car Parking System for a school project, and I've been stuck on this problem for a while now. The goal of the project is to have a maximum of 10 parking slots, where the user is able to select which slot they want to be in from a drop-down box. So far, I've managed to get the drop-down box to show along with the 10 parking slots, but I could never get it to update on the row selected on the drop-down box. Here are my codes so far:

```
<?php

$CustomerName = $PlateNumber = $CarName = $CarColor = $Slot = "";
$CustomerNameErr = $PlateNumberErr = $CarNameErr = $CarColorErr = "";

if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
{
    if(empty($_POST["CustomerName"]))
    {
        $CustomerNameErr = "Please fill out this field";
    }
    else
    {
        $CustomerName = $_POST["CustomerName"];
    }

    if(empty($_POST["PlateNumber"]))
    {
        $PlateNumberErr = "Please fill out this field";
    }
    else
    {
        $PlateNumber = $_POST["PlateNumber"];
    }

    if(empty($_POST["CarName"]))
    {
        $CarNameErr = "Please fill out this field";
    }
    else
    {
        $CarName = $_POST["CarName"];
    }

    if(empty($_POST["CarColor"]))
    {
        $CarColorErr = "Please fill out this field";
    }
    else
    {
        $CarColor = $_POST["CarColor"];
    }
}

?>

<form class="logintext" method="POST" action="<?php htmlspecialchars("PHP_SELF");?>">

    <br><b>Register Parking</b><br><br>
    <!-- Slot select-->
    Select Slot: <select name="slots">
        <?php 
            $mysqli = NEW mysqli('localhost','root','','sad');

            $slot_query = $mysqli->query("SELECT slot FROM parkingrecords");
            while ($rows = $slot_query->fetch_assoc())
            {
                $SlotVal = $rows['Slot'];
                echo "<option value='".$rows['Slot']."'>".$rows['Slot']."</option>";
            }
        ?>
    </select><br><br>

    <!-- fill-up form; this is the data that replaces the "empty" slots on the table-->
    Customer Name: &nbsp; <input type="text" name="CustomerName" value="<?php echo $CustomerName ?>"><br>
    <span class="error"><?php echo $CustomerNameErr; ?></span><br>

    Plate Number: &nbsp; <input type="text" name="PlateNumber" value="<?php echo $PlateNumber ?>"><br>
    <span class="error"><?php echo $PlateNumberErr; ?></span><br>

    Car Name: &nbsp; <input type="text" name="CarName" value="<?php echo $CarName ?>"><br>
    <span class="error"><?php echo $CarNameErr; ?></span><br>

    Car Color: &nbsp; <input type="text" name="CarColor" value="<?php echo $CarColor ?>"><br>
    <span class="error"><?php echo $CarColorErr; ?></span><br>

    <input type="submit" value="Register">

</form>

<?php 

include("carpark_connections.php");

if($Slot && $CustomerName && $PlateNumber && $CarName && $CarColor)
{
    $query = mysqli_query($connections, "UPDATE parkingrecords SET CustomerName = '$CustomerName', PlateNumber = '$PlateNumber', CarName = '$CarName', CarColor = '$CarColor' WHERE Slot = '$SlotVal' ");

    echo "<script language = 'javascript'>alert('You have been registered!')</script>";
    echo "<script>window.location.href='ParkNow.php';</script>";
} ...
```

Nothing happens when I try to submit the update form. The data I type in doesn't seem to go anywhere at all, but it still executes the query since the javascript alert is working. I don't know what I'm missing here. Any help would be appreciated!

EDIT: I fixed a little bit of the code and now instead of nothing happening, it just keeps on updating the 10th slot no matter which slot i select on the dropdown.

Comment: See about injection and the importance of prepared and bound queries

Comment: Your code sequence is creating an issue you write some PHP code before form and some after the form and in your form code you use same variable  $Slot = $rows['slot']; to assign a slot to select drop-down so whenever you trying to submit form it always $Slot value is 10 which last value in your while loop

Comment: @Sachin I see, I kind of figured that to be the case as well, but idk how to fix it. You said that in my code I had the same variables of $Slot for my $rows['slot']. Does that mean that I can fix this by assigning it a different variable or is there something else I still need to do?

Comment: Yes you can use different variable is a better option or use like this 
echo "<option value='".$rows['slot']."'>".$rows['slot']."</option>";

Comment: @Sachin i tried that (edited the code above) and it still works like it does before (only updates the 10th row no matter what slot i select). what else do you think i should try?

Comment: I'll post the whole updated code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is an updated code please replace it with this updated code.

```
<?php

    $CustomerName = $PlateNumber = $CarName = $CarColor = $Slot = "";
    $CustomerNameErr = $PlateNumberErr = $CarNameErr = $CarColorErr = "";

    if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
    {
        if(empty($_POST["CustomerName"])){
            $CustomerNameErr = "Please fill out this field";
        }else{
            $CustomerName = $_POST["CustomerName"];
        }
        if(empty($_POST["PlateNumber"])){
            $PlateNumberErr = "Please fill out this field";
        }else{
            $PlateNumber = $_POST["PlateNumber"];
        }
        if(empty($_POST["CarName"])){
            $CarNameErr = "Please fill out this field";
        }else{
            $CarName = $_POST["CarName"];
        }
        if(empty($_POST["CarColor"])){
            $CarColorErr = "Please fill out this field";
        }else{
            $CarColor = $_POST["CarColor"];
        }
        if(empty($_POST["slots"])){
            $SlotErr = "Please fill out this field";
        }else{
            $Slot = $_POST["slots"];
        }
    }
    ?>

    <form class="logintext" method="POST" action="<?php htmlspecialchars("PHP_SELF");?>">

        <br><b>Register Parking</b><br><br>
        <!-- Slot select-->
        Select Slot: <select name="slots">
            <?php 
                $mysqli = NEW mysqli('localhost','root','','sad');

                $slot_query = $mysqli->query("SELECT slot FROM parkingrecords");
                while ($rows = $slot_query->fetch_assoc())
                {
                    $SlotVal = $rows['Slot'];
                    echo "<option value='$SlotVal'>$SlotVal</option>";
                }
            ?>
        </select><br><br>

        <!-- fill-up form; this is the data that replaces the "empty" slots on the table-->
        Customer Name: &nbsp; <input type="text" name="CustomerName" value="<?php echo $CustomerName ?>"><br>
        <span class="error"><?php echo $CustomerNameErr; ?></span><br>

        Plate Number: &nbsp; <input type="text" name="PlateNumber" value="<?php echo $PlateNumber ?>"><br>
        <span class="error"><?php echo $PlateNumberErr; ?></span><br>

        Car Name: &nbsp; <input type="text" name="CarName" value="<?php echo $CarName ?>"><br>
        <span class="error"><?php echo $CarNameErr; ?></span><br>

        Car Color: &nbsp; <input type="text" name="CarColor" value="<?php echo $CarColor ?>"><br>
        <span class="error"><?php echo $CarColorErr; ?></span><br>

        <input type="submit" value="Register">

    </form>

    <?php 

    include("carpark_connections.php");

    if($Slot && $CustomerName && $PlateNumber && $CarName && $CarColor)
    {
        $query = mysqli_query($connections, "UPDATE parkingrecords SET CustomerName = '$CustomerName', PlateNumber = '$PlateNumber', CarName = '$CarName', CarColor = '$CarColor' WHERE Slot = '$Slot' ");

        echo "<script language = 'javascript'>alert('You have been registered!')</script>";
        echo "<script>window.location.href='ParkNow.php';</script>";
    }
```

Comment: sorry but i couldn't get this to work either... i think it's because the $Slot in the WHERE query isn't really holding a value from the dropdown list, so the data I type in the form isn't going anywhere.

Either that or im doing something wrong again...

Comment: Can you try echo the $Slot value so we can identify $Sloat recive correct value.

Comment: why you give me down vote? I am trying to solve your problem with your provided code and problem explanation.

Comment: I echo'd the $Slot value and it did output the option i chose in the dropdown text. it turns out that i made a mistake in the code (i think it was just weird quotation marks at work again). Thank you very much! also sorry but i wasnt the one who downvoted, i generally dont downvote people who are trying to help

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a part where should you accept the $_POST['slots']

```
if(empty($_POST["slots"]))
    {
        $slotErr = "Please select value for this field";
    }
    else
    {
        $slot = $_POST["slots"];
    }
```

Comment: i added that and it still doesnt seem to be working... i wonder what else im missing here

Comment: it seems that i was missing quotation marks on the $slot on my WHERE query, but now instead of nothing happening, it always updates the 10th slot no matter which Slot i select on the drop-down.